# Conditionally defining macro in m4 within ifdef

Tags: m4

This is the first time I'm using `m4`, and I'm having difficulty in defining a macro conditionally based on whether or not another macro is already defined.

The problem I'm facing is with the following snippet in my *test.m4* file:

```
ifdef(`MANPAGE', define(_NAME, `NAME'), define(_NAME, `Name'))

_NAME
```

As an analogy in C, what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
#ifdef MANPAGE
#define _NAME "NAME"
#else
#define _NAME "Name"
#endif
```

Now, when I run `m4 -DMANPAGE test.m4`, I get the output **Name**, whereas I expect the output to be **NAME**. Whether or not `-DMANPAGE` is specified, I always get the output **Name**.

I am uncertain where I'm going wrong, and I was unable to find a solution even after referring to the m4 man pages and other online articles. On StackOverflow, I did refer to the following posts which seemed to have some bearing:
[Triple conditional check with ifdef in M4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059432/) and
[Escaping Commas in m4 ifdef Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630945/).

However, I still haven't made any headway. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ifdef(`MANPAGE', `define(_NAME, `NAME')', `define(_NAME, `Name')')
```

I believe the parameters get expanded before passing to `ifdef`

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! However, I'm afraid it doesn't seem to help enclosing the defines within quotes.

Comment: @AbhishekChakravarti it works for me in `m4 (GNU M4) 1.4.19`

Comment: My apologies! You were right. I had missed enclosing the MANPAGE in quotes.